# (Java) No Required SSL certificate was sent (Works fine when used in curl call)

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

So, I'm trying to test out a connection to my company's web server (using 2-way SSL) by using a client certificate in a Java program.
I have tried using the same certificate in a curl call (separated cert and key) and managed to get the desired response.
But when I tried using it in my Java program (combined into pkcs12 format), it gives a 400 Response saying No Required SSL certificate was sent. Why is this happening?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Taufiq's mutual SSL-authentication test");
    org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();
    Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.INFO);

    try {
        final String CERT_ALIAS = "something", CERT_PASSWORD = "something";

        KeyStore identityKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        FileInputStream identityKeyStoreFile = new FileInputStream(new File("src/Cert.p12"));
        identityKeyStore.load(identityKeyStoreFile, CERT_PASSWORD.toCharArray());

        KeyStore trustKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        FileInputStream trustKeyStoreFile = new FileInputStream(new File("src/truststore.jks"));
        trustKeyStore.load(trustKeyStoreFile, CERT_PASSWORD.toCharArray());

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
            // load identity keystore
            .loadKeyMaterial(identityKeyStore, CERT_PASSWORD.toCharArray(), new PrivateKeyStrategy() {
                @Override
                public String chooseAlias(Map<String, PrivateKeyDetails> aliases, Socket socket) {
                    return CERT_ALIAS;
                }
            })
            // load trust keystore
            .loadTrustMaterial(trustKeyStore, null)
            .build();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
            new String[]{"TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1"},
            null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
            .build();

        // Call a SSL-endpoint
        callEndPoint (client);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Boom, we failed: " + ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void callEndPoint(CloseableHttpClient aHTTPClient) {

    try {          
        String ServerUrl = "My Company URL";
        System.out.println("Calling URL: " + ServerUrl);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(ServerUrl);
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        System.out.println("**POST** request Url: " + post.getURI());

        HttpResponse response = aHTTPClient.execute(post);

        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);
        System.out.println("Content:-\n");
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Boom, we failed: " + ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Sample Curl call:
    curl -v --key key.pem --pass ****** --cert cert.pem MyCompanyURL

Comment: It would be useful to see exact command you use in `curl`?

Comment: I would say that, in the client side, you need the **server certificate** and not the client one.

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi I have edited my question to include the curl call

Comment: @VictorCalatramas In my understanding the server cert goes into the truststore and the client cert will be sent when making 2 way ssl calls. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Everything depends on the implementation of the server, what is sure is that client and server need each others certificates (.pem)

Comment: which java version, which imports? these are not all jsse classes. And should you setup the cipher suites too in that library

Answer (score 0):

I presume you know how ssl handshakes work. If not, get acquainted. Then use wireshark to see the ssl handshake. You will get a much better ssl alert detail than some damn http library interpretation. If anything, this is a misleading error.

One sure thing is that your server must trust your client cert, so I assume you have things setup correctly first; you say you have tried curl but you didn't say if it worked.

Finally, I don't recognize these SSL classes, so you are importing something else than the jdk's jsse classes; you may be victim of such library.

Comment: Ok. so can you add the imports, tell us about the ssl lib you are using? Have you tried just the core jdk jsse classes? Make sure you have the SSLSocket.setUseClientMode(true) (which you can't tell by using a library). And again, wireshark will tell why it failed, the where is easier to find without a 3rd party in the way.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the program runs fine when I used the core jdk jsse classes. I used the above program because I was copying one of the examples from the internet.